# Ubuntu 16.04, no sound, no audio output available in sound settings

Tags: 16.04, sound

So all of the sudden, just over a week ago, I couldn't get any sound out of my Lenovo Yoga Pro 2 running Ubuntu 16.04. When I open sound settings there are no options for audio output and it doesn't detect applications that are playing audio. The sound card is working and I've installed a new audio driver but that doesn't do anything.

When I run `aplay -l` the results I get are

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC233 Analog [ALC233 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing pulseaudio-equalizer. The pulseaudio daemon kept failing to start and this was in the syslogs:

```
cat /var/log/syslog* | grep -i pulse

[pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-ladspa-sink" (argument: "sink_name=ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo plugin=mbeq_1197 label=mbeq control=-8.2,-7.6,7.2,6.3,3.0,-1.0,-5.6,-6.3,-4.5,-4.0,1.1,1.2,5.3,7.3,8.2"): initialization failed.
[pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
[pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
[pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

Pulseaudio-equalizer had modified the audioplus configuration and it couldnt start due to one of the new settings. So I cleaned the ~/.config/pulse and after reboot the sound was back.