# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't recognize the headphone anymore. no guide seems to work

Tags: sound, alsa

Since few days my laptop Dell Vostro 15 with Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't recognize the headphone.
I've tried different guide but nothing seems to work.

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=8679292cd1edf1cd9529c9169e0acb4825cad982

Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: Do you test all of this post instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working

Comment: Done, nothing changed.
My sound setting show only HDMI Sound Port.

i got this on aplay -l command

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

End alsamixer show only S/PIDF ports

Comment: I have tried to restore all driver but neither this had any effects

sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2

Comment: I have tried this too without any result:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED. 
using this: [Ubuntu 16.04, no sound, no audio output available in sound settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882971/ubuntu-16-04-no-sound-no-audio-output-available-in-sound-settings)

I cleaned the ~/.config/pulse and after reboot the sound was back.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in ubuntu 17.10.

You have to go to settings sound and put balance all in the right or all in the left, not in the middle. And works.